# Find the dept that is being paid the max salary

Tags: mysql, sql, database, max

I'm a student and am working on a MySql assignment given to us for the holidays.
I have a table that looks something like this :

```
name      dept     salary  
 A       Sales      100
 B       Marketing  200
 C       Sales      800
```

(Sorry I'm new to stackexchange so I don't know how to display a table.)

The question for the query is : *find the dept that is being paid the max salary*.
I entered the following query :

```
SELECT dept
     , SUM(salary)
FROM emp
GROUP BY dept
HAVING MAX(SUM(salary));
```

But I am getting the following error:

> 'Invalid use of group function error'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case `salary` sum is unique, you can calculate sum for each `dept` then order records in descending order by aggregated salary and fetch the first record (with the greatest salary):

```
select dept
     , sum(salary) as salary
from tbl
group by dept
order by salary desc
limit 1
```

In case `salary` sum can be the same for multiple `dept`s you can calculate salary sum for each `dept` , then find maximum `salary` sum the same way as explained above and using a `having` clause validate if `salary` sum for each group is equal to the maximum `salary` sum:

```
select dept
from tbl
group by dept 
having sum(salary) = ( select sum(salary) as salary
                       from tbl
                       group by dept
                       order by salary desc
                       limit 1)
```

Comment: It worked ! Thanks... But can you please explain the query(I'm new to sql do it would help...)